# multiplication on left coset

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I was reading about properties of the [left coset on wikipedia](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Group_acts_on_left_coset_space_of_subgroup_by_left_multiplication), and I found a statement with no justification. The claim:

"Suppose $G$ is a group and $H$ is a subgroup of $G$. Consider the left coset space $G\mid H$, i.e., the collection of left cosets of $H$ in $G$:

$G\mid H =
 \{xH \mid x\in G\}$

Then there exists a natural group action of $G$ on $ G\mid H$ by left multiplication:

$g.(xH)=(gx)H$

In other words, left multiplying any left coset by an element of the group yields a left coset, and this defines an action of the group on the left coset space by left multiplication. Further, the following facts are true about this group action:

1. The stabilizer of the coset $xH$ is the conjugate subgroup $xHx^{-1}$."

Since a proof of these claims wasn't included, my question is how to go about proving that $g.(xH)=(gx)H$ and that the stabilizer of $xH$ is indeed $xHx^{-1}$. Thanks for any help

Comment: See the Lemma here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3679785/750041

Comment: Since the link acutally goes beyond your need, I prefer to put the relavant part of it as an answer here. In the occasion, I've numbered the main steps, so as to make easier referring to them in case something was unclear.

Answer (score 1):

$g(xH)=(gx)H$ is simply the associativity of the group law.

As for $\DeclareMathOperator{\stab}{Stab}\stab(xH)$: first check, again by assciativity, that $xHx^{-1}\subset \stab(xH)$.

Conversely, if $g$ stabilises $xH$, this means $\;g(xH)=(gx)H\subset xH $, whence $\;H\subset x^{-1}xH=H$, i.e. $x^{-1}gx\in H$, whence (left multiplying both sides by $x$ and right multiplying by $x^{-1}$):
$$g\in xHx^{-1}$$

Answer (score 0):

In this proof we will consider the operation of the quotient group $G/H$

Let $a,b \in G$ such that: $aH=bH $

Note that : $aH=bH  \Rightarrow a^{-1}b \in H$

Now we will show that the operation $(aH) (bH )= (ab)H$ is well defined.

That is if $a_1H=a_2H$ and $b_1H=b_2H$ then we only need to show that $(a_1b_1)H=(a_2b_2)H$

From the above comment, we know that $a_1H=a_2H \Rightarrow a_1^{-1}a_2 \in H$.
This clearly implies that $\exists h \in H : a_2=a_1 h$

Similarly : $\exists h^{'} \in H : b_2=b_1 h^{'} $

So: $a_2b_2=(a_1h)(b_1h^{'}) =a_1(b_1b_1^{-1})(hb_1h^{'})=a_1b_1(b_1^{-1}hb_1h^{'})=a_1b_1h^{''}$

Since we are examining the operation of the quotient group $G/H$, we have that $H$ has to be a normal subgroup of G. 
This means $b_1^{-1}hb_1 \in H$ so as also $h^{'} \in H$ we have that $b_1^{-1}hb_1h^{'}=h^{''} \in H$ .

By the logic used earlier $a_2b_2= a_1b_1 h^{''}$ with $h^{''} \in H$ means that $(a_2b_2)H=(a_1b_1)H$ 
(that is, they are in the same cost)

So as the above operation on the costs of $G$ is well defined.

(I hope this cleared up some things)

Answer (score 0):

By definition of stabilizer, for this action we have:

$$\operatorname{Stab}(gH)=\{g'\in G\mid g'gH=gH\} \tag 1$$

**Lemma**. $\operatorname{Stab}(gH)=gHg^{-1}$.

*Proof*.

\begin{alignat}{1}
g'\in \operatorname{Stab}(gH) &\Rightarrow \exists h,h'\in H\mid g'gh=gh' \\
&\Rightarrow \exists h,h'\in H\mid g'=gh'(gh)^{-1}=gh'h^{-1}g^{-1} \\
&\Rightarrow \exists h''\in H\mid g'=gh''g^{-1} \\
&\Rightarrow g'\in gHg^{-1} \\
\tag 2
\end{alignat}

and thence $\operatorname{Stab}(gH)\subseteq gHg^{-1}$. Viceversa:

\begin{alignat}{1}
g'\in gHg^{-1} &\Rightarrow g'g \in gH \\
&\Rightarrow g'gH\subseteq gH \\
\tag 3
\end{alignat}

Now:

\begin{alignat}{1}
gH\subseteq g'gH &\iff \forall h \in H, \exists h'\in H\mid gh=g'gh' \\
&\iff \forall h \in H, \exists h'\in H\mid gh=(gh''g^{-1})gh'=gh''h' \\
&\iff h'=(gh'')^{-1}gh=h''^{-1}g^{-1}gh=h''^{-1}h \\
\tag 4
\end{alignat}

Since $h''$ exists by hypothesis ("*Viceversa...*"), such a $h'$ exists, and then indeed:

$$gH\subseteq g'gH \tag 5$$

Therefore, $g'\in gHg^{-1} \Rightarrow g'gH=gH \Rightarrow g'\in \operatorname{Stab}(gH) \Rightarrow gHg^{-1}\subseteq \operatorname{Stab}(gH)$.

$\Box$