# $G$ acts $G/H$ with $H$ subgroup of $G$. Unique orbit.

Tags: group-theory

Studying group actions I came across the following observation that they mention but do not prove. I can't understand it.

Let $G$ group and $H$ subgroup of $G$. Let $G\times G/H\to G/H, a\cdot (bH)=abH$ action. Here there a unique orbit.

Why here there a unique orbit? I  can't prove that $orb(aH)=orb(bH)$ for $a,b\in G$

Comment: $b H=(ba^{-1})\cdot(aH)$ for every $a,b\in G$.

Comment: I see!. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

By the Orbit-Stabilizer Theorem:

$$|O(aH)||\operatorname{Stab}(aH)|=|G|, \space\forall a \in G \tag 1$$

Now, $\operatorname{Stab}(aH)=aHa^{-1}$ (see *e.g.* [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3679785/750041)), whence $|\operatorname{Stab}(aH)|=|aHa^{-1}|=|H|$ (because $h\mapsto aha^{-1}$ is a bijection from $H$ to $aHa^{-1}$). Therefore, by $(1)$:

$$|O(aH)|=\frac{|G|}{|H|}=|G/H|, \space\forall a \in G \tag 2$$

so there is one orbit, only. This way for $G$ finite. More generally ($G$ possibly infinite):

\begin{alignat}{1}
|O(aH)| &\stackrel{(a)}{=} [G:\operatorname{Stab}(aH)] \\
&\stackrel{\color{white}{()}}{=} [G:aHa^{-1}] \\
&\stackrel{(b)}{=} [G:H] \\
&\stackrel{\color{white}{()}}{=} |G/H|, \space\forall a \in G \\
\tag 3
\end{alignat}

and the conclusion keeps the same.

---

(a) Orbit-Stabilizer Theorem.

(b) See e.g. [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3695309/750041).