# Are there sufficient conditions on $H,K \lneq G$, $H\ne K$, such that $[G:H]=[G:K]$ for infinite $G$?

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $H,K$ distinct proper subgroups of $G$. If $G$ is finite, then $|H|=|K|\Rightarrow [G:H]=[G:K]$. Now, if we move to the infinite $G$ case, and take *e.g.* $G=\mathbb{Z}$ and $H_n:=n\mathbb{Z}$, then $[G:H_n]=n$ and then, in spite of the fact that $|H_n|=|H_m|, \forall m,n>1$ ( here I consider the bijection $H_m\to H_n$ defined by $k \mapsto (k/m)n$ ), we get $[G:H_n]\ne[G:H_m]$ as soon as $m\ne n$.

> Are there sufficient conditions on $H,K \lneq G$, $H\ne K$, such that $[G:H]=[G:K]$ for infinite $G$?

I was guessing that the case $K=gHg^{-1}$ worked, but I can't build up a bijection $f\colon G/H\to G/gHg^{-1}$ (here by "$/$" I denote the set of left cosets).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Conjugates *do* have the same index. The bijection you are looking for is:
$$aH\mapsto gaHg^{-1}$$
The main thing to worry about is whether or not $gaHg^{-1}$ is actually a coset of $gHg^{-1}$, and you can see that it is by viewing it as $gag^{-1}\cdot gHg^{-1}$.

The map is well-defined and injective as:
$$\begin{align*}
gaHg^{-1}&=gbHg^{-1}\\
\Leftrightarrow\: &gag^{-1}(gbg^{-1})^{-1}\in gHg^{-1}\\
\Leftrightarrow\: &gab^{-1}g^{-1}\in gHg^{-1}\\
\Leftrightarrow\: &ab^{-1}\in H\\
\Leftrightarrow\: &aH=bH
\end{align*}
$$
It is surjective as it is reversible (just as $gHg^{-1}$ is a conjugate of $H$, we have that $H$ is a conjugate of $gHg^{-1}$ so we can analogously define $bgHg^{-1}\mapsto bH$).

Comment: Thank you, very clear. That's the map that I couldn't see.