# Is a sufficient condition that $H$, $K$ $\leq G$ such that $|H|=|K|$ and $[G:H]$ are finites to conclude that $[G:K]=[G:H]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, infinite-groups

Let $G$ an infinite group, $H$ and $K$ proper subgroups of $G$ such that $|H|$ and $|K|$ are finite and $|H|=|K|$, also $[G:H]$ is finite. **The question is:** With this hypothesis can I conclude that $[G:K]=[G:H]$?

I try to figure it out that the property of finitude in the index and the equality of the cardinality of the subgroups is sufficient to conclude that the index of G in K is also finite and equal to [G:H].

In the question [Are there sufficient conditions on ,⪇, ≠, such that [:]=[:]for infinite ?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3695246/are-there-sufficient-conditions-on-h-k-lneq-g-h-ne-k-such-that-gh-g) its clearly the answer to finite groups but I'm stuck with infinite groups.

I would be very thankful for an answer to this question.

Comment: If both $H$ and $[G:H]$ are finite, then $G$ can't be finite.  Since the object you're looking for doesn't exist, you can conclude anything you want about it.  You can even believe six impossible things about $G$ before breakfast.

Comment: @RobertShore You mean "$G$ must be finite" or equivalently "$G$ can't be infinite".

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: @DerekHolt Yes, thank you for clarifying my error.

Comment: Thank for your support!

Comment: You're welcome, @AugustoLP. Please don't forget to accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall:

$$|G|=[G:H]|H|.$$

If both factors of the RHS are finite, then so is the LHS.

Comment: Doesn't what you mention happen only when G is finite?

Comment: No. It follows from $$[G:K]=[G:H][H:K]$$ for $G\ge H\ge K$ by setting $K=1$, @AugustoLP. Most undergraduate courses don't prove it in full generality as it can get difficult. I will find a proof; I was looking at one earlier . . .

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3333470/104041), @AugustoLP.

Comment: Thanks a lot! @Shaun

Comment: You're welcome, @AugustoLP. I'm glad I could help.

Comment: I think [this proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/749567/104041) (in the same thread) does not assume $K\unlhd H\unlhd G$.